# Change graph layout (aka. node positioning algorithm) in pyvis

Tags: python, graph, networkx, pyvis

When using `networkx.draw()` it is possible to specify [different node positioning algorithms](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout) that change the graph layout using the [`pos`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html) keyword argument. For example:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a graph
G = nx.dodecahedral_graph()

# draw with different layouts
plt.figure()
nx.draw(G,pos=nx.circular_layout(G))
plt.figure()
nx.draw(G,pos=nx.spring_layout(G))
```

gives you these two different layouts:

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to do this using `pyvis`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, mainly there are four types:

- BarnesHut
- ForceAtlas2Based
- Repulsion
- HierachicalRepulsion

you can check their effects by setting the option `show_buttons(filter_=["physics"])`:

```
net = Network(...)
net.show_buttons(filter_=["physics"])
```

on the drop-down that appears (the option 'solver')